# Service callback in ros2 Python is not firing

Tags: ros2

i just wrote a simple service program to print numbers using a service
but is not working as intended

ros2 - humble

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node

from msg_srv_launch.srv import SetParams

class printsrv(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("printsrv")
        self.server_ = self.create_service(SetParams, "setparams", self.callback_data)  
        self.get_logger().info("server has been started.")

    def callback_data(self, request, response):
        self.get_logger().info(str(request.pendulum_mass) + " " + str(request.pendulum_length))
        return response
    
def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    node = printsrv()
    rclpy.spin(node)
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am using this command in another terminal

> ros2 service call /inverted_pendulum/set_params
> inverted_pendulum_sim/srv/SetParams '{pendulum_mass : 0.0,
> pendulum_length : 300}'

it just getting like this

> waiting for service to become available...

i am running the serving too but still it is waiting for it and I even checked the server list in that to I can see the my server running

I don't know if might be helpful or not but when I press ctrl+c I get this

```
[INFO] [1704436354.678095187] [printsrv]: server has been started.
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/guru/humble_projects/Octobotics_Coding_Assignment/install/inverted_pendulum_sim/lib/inverted_pendulum_sim/printsrv", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('inverted-pendulum-sim==0.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'printsrv')())
  File "/home/guru/humble_projects/Octobotics_Coding_Assignment/install/inverted_pendulum_sim/lib/python3.10/site-packages/inverted_pendulum_sim/test.py", line 29, in main
    rclpy.spin(node)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/__init__.py", line 222, in spin
    executor.spin_once()
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 739, in spin_once    self._spin_once_impl(timeout_sec)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 728, in _spin_once_impl
    handler, entity, node = self.wait_for_ready_callbacks(timeout_sec=timeout_sec)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 711, in wait_for_ready_callbacks
    return next(self._cb_iter)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 608, in _wait_for_ready_callbacks
    wait_set.wait(timeout_nsec)
KeyboardInterrupt
[ros2run]: Interrupt
```

Comment: Did you add your node in setup.py?

Comment: @Hem92j yes i did

Comment: ```def callback_data(self, request, response):
        self.get_logger().info(str(request.pendulum_mass) + " " + str(request.pendulum_length))``` also add return response in your callback. Also make your sure terminal is sourced.

Comment: @Hem92j i tried your approach to same result, i have updated the question please check if it is helpful or not

Comment: why do your console output has different logging output than node? In your code it says "server has been started" and in your console it says "Add two ints server has been started"´. Did you build your program again?

Comment: @Hem92j Sorry i have copied the wrong but it is the same one, I was trying to debug

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150664/discussion-between-hem92j-and-pedakolimi-harish).

Answer (score 0):

Logs from the console don't match the `get_logger()` function. How do you build your workspace?

[IGNORE THIS PART] After reading comments I suppose that you are using `setup.py` but as far as I know for C++ files you need *CMakeList.txt* instead. I am not sure if `setup.py` can be used by colcon during building (here in the docs there is only info about *CMakeList.txt* [CppPublisherSubscriberDocs](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Writing-A-Simple-Cpp-Publisher-And-Subscriber.html). Also here [ServiceCppDocs](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Writing-A-Simple-Cpp-Service-And-Client.html). In both cases Cpp -> CmakeList.txt so I would try this approach. [IGNORE THIS PART]

What do you see when you type `ros2 service list`?

If you would like to check if your `setup.py` is really working and code has been compiled properly , you can remove *install* and *build* folders from your workspace, run `colcon build` or `colcon build --packages-select <here the name of the package>` and check if you will be able to run the code again or it won't be found.

Comment: i am using python package thats by I have setup.py instead of CMakeList.txt
and I I sure of it that this package is working properly because I have ran a few nodes from ros2 doc like this one and it worked perfectly
https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Writing-A-Simple-Py-Service-And-Client.html#write-the-service-node

Comment: Sorry, I am working so much with Cpp and Python interchangable lately that I though that is Cpp code. Sorry, my mistake. But try to remove install and build folders inside your workspace and try to `colcon build` again to check. If you did something wrong when editing `setup.py` it's not running your latest file, but it will run remaining file inside install folder